# Listener for Windows Event log

Tags: java, jna, event-log

I could use the below java JNA code to read a windows event log

```java
EventLogIterator iter = new EventLogIterator("EventLogName");
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    EventLogRecord record = iter.next();
    System.out.println(record.getRecordId()
            + ": Event ID: " + record.getEventId()
            + ", Event Type: " + record.getType()
            + ", Event Source: " + record.getSource());
}
```

I want to read/capture only new events.

Is there an option/API in JNA (or any other java library) to listen to windows event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EventLogIterator` has two constructors, one just taking the log name and [the other](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.EventLogIterator.html#EventLogIterator-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-) allowing you to specify a server and flags.

You can pass the parameter `EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ` flag to this constructor, e.g. change your first line to:

```java
new EventLogIterator(null, "EventLogName", WinNT.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ);
```

Since the Event Log Record Id [always increases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-log-records)<sup>1</sup>, if you keep track of the previous highest value of `getRecordId()` then you can stop your iteration when you get to it, and only have new events.

You can easily set up this routine to poll at regular intervals.

---

<sup>1</sup> The recordId's are unsigned and wrap to 0 at the max 32-bit value so the best approach for determining "new" events is to subtract the previous "highest" from the current and test for a positive number.